# Display custom field for logged in user

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to get an acf created custom field via querying all posts.

I tried the following:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ):

    global $current_user;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $author_query = array('post_status' => array( 'draft' ), 
    'author' => $current_user->ID,
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'wpgamail_options',
            'key'       => 'ganalytics_settings',
        ),
    ),);
    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
    while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <?php the_title(); ?> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php $post_date = get_the_date(); echo $post_date; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php $field = get_field('wpgamail_options', $author_posts->the_post()->ID, true); echo $field['nextfetchtime']; ?> //here I get the error
    </td>
    </tr>    
    <?php           
    endwhile;

else :
    echo "You are not logged in. Please log in!";
endif;
?>
```

I get the following error message:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in Unknown on line 0 Call
>   Stack: 3.9772 231600 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:0
>   3.9774 232048 2. require('/home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-blog-header.php') /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:17 4.6285 8745184 3.
>   require_once('/home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-includes/template-loader.php')
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-blog-header.php:19 4.6328 8788784 4.
>   include('/home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/page-create-report.php')
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-includes/template-loader.php:75 1469999466

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong by using the `[get_field()][1]` function?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$author_posts->the_post()->ID` while you should use `get_the_ID()` (not `the_ID()` which displays ID).
Fixed code.

```
<?php 
$field = get_field('wpgamail_options', get_the_ID(), true);
echo $field['nextfetchtime']; ?>
```

Also, you don't need to do `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`.  `$current_user` global already contains current user object.

Answer (score 1):

`$author_posts->the_post()` is used to iterate the post index in the loop, you can't use it to access the current post. Instead, you can use [`get_the_ID`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/):

```
<?php $field = get_field('wpgamail_options', get_the_ID(), true); 
      echo $field['nextfetchtime']; ?>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: This is incorrect. `the_ID()` display ID, while here it needs to be returned. Correct function to use in this case is `get_the_ID()`

Comment: @IgorYavych nice remark thank you ! but just a comment you don't need to add an answer like you resolved an NP-hard problem :D